# If i install Windows 8, will it wipe my other partitions?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

So, i downloaded a Windows 8.1 ISO file and mounted it as a virtual drive using a programme called ***Virtual Clone Drive***.

I'm kinda scared to install Windows 8 but i want to. I want to install Windows 8 but i don't want it to touch any of my other partitions on the same disk. I don't care if it wipes everything on the **C Drive**. I just care about my other 2 partitions.

When i'm installing Windows 8, it gives me **2 options**. "Keep personal files" or "Nothing". If i choose "Keep personal files", will it wipe my other partitions?

Comment: Why not perform a clean installation using a boot DVD/USB drive?

Comment: It should keep all your partitions as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What other partitions do you have on your Hard Drive? Usually Windows would install on your Windows 7 partition and just upgrade your system in place. Choose "Keep my files" to keep all your files in place.

Comment: The partitions i have are D and E, excluding the C drive. Each partition is 300GB. If i choose "Keep **personal** files, will it wipe my partitions, i dont give a damn about the C drive, only my 2 partitions. @Steven

Comment: Windows will not wipe your partitions.

Comment: I'm going to trust you on this one, you seem to know more about this then me, i will reply when Windows 8.1 has finished installing, wish me luck m8